# Shared javax.ejb.Singleton across all wars

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, java-ee-6, cdi

I'm using WebSphere 8.5.5 JEE6 Appserver.

I need a shared `javax.ejb.Singleton`. That 1 singleton needs to be injected into & used by all other wars deployed?

Is this possible? Or does the container create 1 `javax.ejb.Singleton` per application instance rather than 1 per JVM?

And if so are there other options for creating an EJB or CDI Singleton bean 1 per JVM?

Comment: Can you try packing all WARs into a EAR & have shared project with singleton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll tell you the structure of my projects where I have several. War and EJB module shared by all.
first:
must create a project library where you should declare your EJB remote interfaces and your utility classes (ex: clintLib.jar).
second:
in your EJB module you must use the clientLib.jar as lib.
third
In your war module you must use the clientLib.jar as lib.

This way you have access to your EJB module from any war through remote interfaces declared in clientLib.jar. The EJB container will provide access to lookup EJB instances using transparent to you.
my app structure is:
3 war
1 library project
1 EJB project